Finding Longest Almost Palindromic Subsequence (Recursive Solution)
I am working on a problem where I need to find the longest subsequence of a given array that can form a palindrome by removing exactly one element. The solution needs to be implemented recursively.
For example:
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output: 1
Explanation: Every individual number is considered a palindrome, so the longest palindromic subsequence is just one element.
Input: [2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3]
Output: 6
Explanation: The sequence [3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3] can become a palindrome by removing either 5 or 6. This gives a length of 6.
I am trying to test this array [1,2] and it returns 2 instead 1, or [1,2,3,4,1] returns 3 instead 1.
public static int maxPossiblePalindrome(int[] arr) {
    return maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private static int maxPossiblePalHelper(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left > right) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (right - left <= 1) {
        return right - left + 1;
    }
    
    if (arr[left] == arr[right]) {
        return 2 + maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, left + 1, right - 1);
    } else {
        return Math.max(maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, left + 1, right), 
                        maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, left, right - 1));
    }


If the source of this problem has a web page, it would be polite, and possibly helpful to include a link to that page. It might have a web page, for example,  if it is from a programming practice / challenge site.

@OldDogProgrammer This problem is similar to this.

I leave you a code, which solves the problem, although it only uses a little bit of recursion.
public int findLargestPossiblePalindrome( int[] arr ) {
     // we call "search", starting with the largest word size and “0” as the initial item
   for( int wordSize = arr.length; wordSize > 0; wordSize -- ) {
      if( search( arr, wordSize, 0 ) ) return wordSize;
   }
   return 1;
}

boolean search( int[] arr, int wordSize, int ini ) {
     // we call "createWord", if return "false", we do a recursion, increasing the value of 
     // “ini”, if this is not possible, we return “false”.
   if( createWord( arr, wordSize, ini ) ) return true;
   if( ini + wordSize < arr.length ) return search( arr, wordSize, ini + 1 );
   return false;
}

boolean createWord( int h[], int wordSize, int ini ) {
     // we create the word to be parsed, skipping in each iteration one of the item's
   for( int k = ini; k < wordSize + ini; k ++ ) {
      String pali = "";
      for( int j = ini; j < wordSize + ini; j ++ ) {
         if( k != j ) pali += h[ j ];
      }
      if( isPalindrome( pali ) ) return true;
   }
   return false;
}

boolean isPalindrome( String word ) {
   for( int i = 0, j = word.length() - 1; i < word.length() / 2; i ++, j -- ) {
      if( word.charAt( i ) != word.charAt( j ) ) return false;
   }
   return true;
}


There are a few conditions missing.
You can use a memoization array to recursively solve this problem using dynamic programming:
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static int maxPossiblePalindrome(int[] arr) {
        int[][] memo = new int[arr.length][arr.length];
        for (int[] row : memo) {
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        }
        return maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, 0, arr.length - 1, memo);
    }

    private static int maxPossiblePalHelper(int[] arr, int left, int right, int[][] memo) {
        if (left > right) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (left == right) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (memo[left][right] != -1) {
            return memo[left][right];
        }

        if (arr[left] == arr[right]) {
            memo[left][right] = 2 + maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, left + 1, right - 1, memo);
        } else {
            memo[left][right] = Math.max(
                    maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, left + 1, right, memo),
                    maxPossiblePalHelper(arr, left, right - 1, memo));
        }

        return memo[left][right];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(maxPossiblePalindrome(new int[] { 1, 2 }));
        System.out.println(maxPossiblePalindrome(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 }));
        System.out.println(maxPossiblePalindrome(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }));
        System.out.println(maxPossiblePalindrome(new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3 }));
        System.out.println(maxPossiblePalindrome(new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 1 }));
    }
}



Here we use a 2D array memo to store results for dynamic programming subproblems defined by indices (left, right).
Each cell of memo[left][right] holds the length of the longest palindromic subsequence for the subarray arr[left...right].

These are the base cases for recursion:

If left > right, the subsequence length is 0.
If left == right, the subsequence length is 1 (meaning that a single element is a palindrome itself).
If arr[left] == arr[right], the length is 2 + the length of the longest subsequence within arr[left+1...right-1].

Otherwise, it is the maximum of the lengths from these two possibilities:

We exclude the left element: longestPalHelper(arr, left + 1, right, memo).
We exclude the right element: longestPalHelper(arr, left, right - 1, memo).

Time and space complexities are O(N^2).
